# Get nested distibution list members

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to retrieve all the members of a distribution list which contains multiple other distribution lists.

Example: A distribution list contains members John and Jack. It further contains DLs - SampleA, SampleB and SampleC.

This code retrieves members John and Jack but not the members of the DLs inside it. Is there a way to get the members of DLs - SampleA, SampleB and SampleC?

```
Sub DLu()

Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim olNmspc As Outlook.Namespace
Dim objRecip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim objMembers As AddressEntries
Dim objMember As AddressEntry
Dim dMemCnt As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set objOL = New Outlook.Application

Set olNmspc = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
olNmspc.Logon

Set objRecip = olNmspc.CreateRecipient("Distribution List ")

If objRecip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser Is Nothing Then
    If objRecip.Resolve Then
        Set objMembers = objRecip.AddressEntry.Members

        dMemCnt = objMembers.Count

        For i = 1 To dMemCnt
            Set objMember = objMembers.Item(i)
            Debug.Print objMember
        Next i

    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share an example of the data you have in excel, that makes it easier for people to see what you need.

Comment: have edited the description

Comment: @Nancy have you tried: `objRecip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList`

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that takes a parameter of type `AddressEntries`. Call that function passing `objRecip.AddressEntry.Members` as the parameter. That function can check if `AddressEntry.Members` is not null (where `AddressEntry` object comes from the `AddressEntries` collection) and then call itself recursively.